# How do I compare values within code with values in a separate text document?

Tags: python, file, save

So, I'm pretty new to Python and I have just finished making my first game. At the moment, I have a temporary score system that prints the current score onscreen, but resets to 0 with every restart. I would like to create some sort of 'local save' system that compares the previous highscore with the new highscore and updates it if the new highscore is higher.

My idea was to somehow create a separate text file in which the highscore will be stored and saved. Is there any way I can compare the score within my code to the 'score' in the text file, and overwrite the current 'score' in the text file?
I'll be very thankful for constructive responses!

Comment: You can open a file with `open(filename)`

Comment: Thank you, but that I know. I was more thinking about how I can compare the file's content (the highscore) with the score in my code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, clarify what exactly are you struggling with. What have you done so far? Have you problems reading the file? Overwriting stored value?

Comment: You can read the content of the file you opened and save it in a variable. Then you can compare it and write the higher result back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to overwrite a new score:
The score will be saved in `score.txt`

```
def overwrite(new_score):
    with open("score.txt",'w') as f:
        f.write(str(new_score))
```

You can get the old score in the file like so

```
def get_score():
    with open("score.txt",'r') as f:
        x = f.readlines()[0]
        return int(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json

def save_score(score):
    with open("score.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(score, f)

def read_score():
    with open("score.json", "r") as f:
        score=json.load(f)
    return score

save_score(123)
score = read_score()
print(score)
```

Technically you don't need to use `json` but I would prefer to use for storage rather than just writing the value directly in the text file